# VBA: Where to add source formatting and column width?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA and learning on my own. I was able to build a code that searches for a value (previously define as "Number") on all sheets and for those sheets that have the specific value in an specific cell it will copy a range from the sheet and then paste it in a new worksheet. It is worth saying that I did not use copy and paste (see code below). The code works just fine, but I would like the new sheet to keep the same formatting as the source. I have tried a couple of things, but the stuff that works means I have to use `Copy`/`Paste` type coding, which later in the code gives me problems since it changes the `ActiveSheet`. Other attempts do not work. In addition I would like to have a fix column width for the ranges that are paste into the new sheet.

A piece of the code in question is below. FYI = the variable `Number` is defined earlier in the code. Also, earlier in the code I create the new sheet.

**My Questions:**

1. Foe the code below, is there a way to keep the formatting from the source, without having to use "copy" and "paste" type coding.
2. To the code below, can I somehow fix the width of the columns where the new staff are going to be paste?

If you have a better, more elegant way to write the code, I would appreciate it.

```
For k = 1 To wscount - 1
    If Worksheets(k).Range("F2").Value = Number Then
        j = j + 1
        Worksheets(wscount + 1).Range(Cells(1, 1 + j), Cells(100, 1 + j)).Value = Worksheets(k).Range("F1:F100").Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you were to use copy/paste, you could use .PasteSpecial xlValuesAndNumberFormats and also xlPasteColumnWidths.  I am not positive if this can be in the same line, but would be simple enough to have two lines of code to show each pastspecial option.

Comment: You may need to set the formats you want one at a time e.g. to copy from the source format background colour or font colour then you duplicate the line that sets the value and change `.value` to `.font.color` or `.interior.color`.  I can't think of another way.

Comment: for the column width you can use `.width` but you will only need to do this once on each column so it may be worth putting in an if statement (if J =1 then set column width) so that you're not setting it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign property value of the source cell to target cell just like what you do with value property.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyValueAndFormat()
    For k = 1 To wscount - 1
        If Worksheets(k).Range("F2").Value = Number Then
            j = j + 1
            Worksheets(wscount + 1).Range(Cells(1, 1 + j), Cells(100, 1 + j)).Value = Worksheets(k).Range("F1:F100").Value

            'call setFormat method
            setFormat Worksheets(k).Range("F1:F100"), Worksheets(wscount + 1).Range(Cells(1, 1 + j), Cells(100, 1 + j))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub setFormat(source As Range, target As Range)
    'set target format equal to source format
    With target
        .Value = source.Value
        .Interior.Color = source.Interior.Color
        .Font.FontStyle = source.Font.FontStyle
        'add others property to format

        'call AutoFit method to set column width
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @justme - Use assignment operator makes your code run faster in comparing with paste method.